# How to check the type of an HTML element using jsoup

Tags: java, css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

Given a HTML code snippet,

```
<div align="right">...<div>
<p class="text2">abc</p>
```

I have used jsoup to fetch all elements with their attribute, `align` set to `right`. Now I want to select the next sibling which i do using, `el.nextElementSibling()`

How do I verify that the next element is a `p` HTML element with a class of `text2`? I am new to jsoup and I am learning as I code. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Element#getTagName`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#tagName%28%29), which gives you the name of the tag for that element. That same API page also gives you [`Element#classNames`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#classNames%28%29) and a couple of other ways to look at the `class` attribute.

Comment: That will give me `p`. What about checking the `class`? Thanks!

Comment: @SoulSlayer: Just a little further up on the same API page.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer answers the original post fine.

But to answer
"That will give me p. What about checking the class? Thanks! "

The answer would be `e.className()` where `e` is some `Element`.